# Status for ofline/online user in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to check the online status of my site by monitering it on the admin side, for such purpose i add the below code to my user index page...

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{

    $setLogged= mysql_query("UPDATE signup SET Status = 'Ofline' WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location:signin.php');
}
else  {
    $setLogged= mysql_query("UPDATE signup SET Status = 'Online' WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'") or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

the code work and update the status field only when the user login but it will not update it after the user is logout...?
what is the error.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement checks to see if `$_SESSION['user']` is not set. Then in that code block you try to use `$_SESSION['user']` in your query. You are trying to use a variable you know doesn't exist (and has no value).

Comment: I don't see what code example I can provide you. 
You should mark the user as offline when they logout *before* you empty their session. That's really what it boils down to.